Geometry Nodes - Sample Index weired behavior
I've made an Object containing three points.
Via GN I've generated an Arrow by sampling index 0 and 1 as you can see in the screenshot.
I want to switch the direction of the arrow by changing die Index at the sample index node.

0, 1 = everything works fine
1, 0 = no line at all
1, 2 = messy result

Maybe you have an idea?


You can upload the file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Code review and bug hunting are off-topic to this site, try asking on https://blenderartists.org/ or discord. I know this is harsh but a post like this doesn't benefit future visitors.

I suppose, you use Curve Line node in direction mode, while inputs are global coordinates. To make a direction, subtract the second position from the first.


Thank you. Exactly that was the Problem. I used the secon vector as Direction vector. Embarrassing :(
